# Css clear all styles for specific elements

Tags: css

I have a few stylesheets that beautifully style all my elements within the  tag.

I do have one specific  that I need to populate with some custom html (from the database).

Is there a way to ignore all styles only within my  element?  or am I out of luck here.

Comment: can you post an example? I'm confused what your question is...

Comment: can you post some html and css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't clear styles, I am taking a shot in the dark here on your question.

But you will have to RESET your styles for a particualar element:

```
div.reset{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 etc;
}
```

for something like:

`<div class="reset">something</div>`

that way you will reset your styling of that particular element.

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting I'd have to be specific with resetting. Thanks Jakub